# Communication between two closed android applications

Tags: android

I have 2 apps on one device. The server sends push to both applications. I want the first application that received the push to show a notification, and the second should do nothing. How can I check that the first app already showed a notification?
Apps can be closed. I use FirebaseMessagingService for wake up.

I need this because the user can have only one app installed or both.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this on the client without a race condition.  The best way to assure it is to have one app check if the other is installed and not register with Firebase if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is just your server send notification to only one app. But if it is not possible, you can use Broadcast receiver I think.
You can use Broadcast receiver to communicate between two application.
In app B, for example declare broadcast receiver like follow:

```xml
<receiver android:name=".MyBCReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="what.ever.you.want" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And from app A.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
intent.setAction("what.ever.you.want");
intent.putExtra("key","data");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.app.b","com.app.b.MainActivity"));  
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then your app B, you can just make a mark using sharedPreference to not make a notification again.

Comment: Implicit broadcast resgistred on manifest don't work on Android 8 and more, see link : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Service** with [Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl) to create a programming interface to communicate with each other.

For Android 11 (API level 30) you may also need to specify a query with the package of the app you want to interact with:

```
<manifest package="com.example.app">
  <queries>
    <!-- Specific apps you interact with, eg: -->
    <package android:name="com.example.service" />
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```